# Partition for embedded linux before flashing the SD card

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, buildroot

I am trying to build a embedded Linux system for `karo imx6 8033 som` with 4GB SD card on it by using `buildroot` to build rootfs, Configuring kernel 4.11. I am using `mfg` tool to write the system on module. After flashing the SD card, I see that rootfs partition is just 300MB.

```
# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root               282.5M    136.7M    130.8M  51% /
devtmpfs                342.1M         0    342.1M   0% /dev
```

uboot

```
TX6DL U-Boot > mmc part

Partition Map for MMC device 0  --   Partition Type: DOS

Part    Start Sector    Num Sectors     UUID            Type
  1     2048            30720           0cc66cc0-01     0c
  2     32768           614400          0cc66cc0-02     83
  3     647168          7086080         0cc66cc0-03     83
```

Each block is 512B so 614400*512=300MB. It is not enough for my work.

I want to learn in which step this configuration of partition is set while configuring rootfs, kernel or u-boot? MFG tool also has configuration file. If this partition is set while sending rootfs, kernel and U-boot, which parameter of MFG tool should I change to enhance the rootfs partition?

there is a way  [at this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311961/uboot-write-kernel-into-mmc-partition/371949#371949) after flashing the SD card. But I need a solution before flashing it.

Comment: It looks like your question is about the MFG tool for your board. Im guessing that your MFG tool is a script customized for your board, locate where the MFG executable lives and look at the steps. You may find it easier to 'manually' create the partitions and copy u-boot, kernel, and rootfs to the SD card. In short I think the MFG tool sets the partition size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.
In my case, I have chanced script named ucl2.xml file in Profiles/TX6/OS FIRMWARE in MFG Tool file. karo TX6 board has 4 GB MMC, so I made changes under "LINUX-MMC" In line 104

```
    <CMD state="Updater" type="push" body="$ [ -b /dev/emmc ] && (echo label-id:0x0cc66cc0; echo size=30720,type=c; echo size=614400,type=83; echo type=83) | sfdisk /dev/emmc"> Partitioning...</CMD>
```

first "echo size" represents first partition above. second represents second partition. just add second partition "Num Sectors" with third partition "Num Sectors" and change the 614400 with 7700480